# Is it safe to Invoke on a Dispatcher when the corresponding Window has been closed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I have a window with that is shown to the user as a busy spinner when batch operations are being executed.  An external class manages the batch operations and displays the busy spinner window when the list of operations takes longer than a specified amount of time.

```
class BatchOperationManager {

  int timeToDelay = 1000;

  void Execute()
  {
        BusyWindow window = new BusyWindow();
        window.Loaded += BeginBatchOperations;
        DelayOpening(window);
        window.ShowDialog();
  }

  void BeginBatchOperations(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       var thread = new Thread(ExecuteBatchOperations);
       thread.Start(sender);
  }

  void ExecuteBatchOperations(object window)
  {
       var busyWindow = (BusyWindow)window;
       //do work
       window.Dispatcher.Invoke(window.Close);
  }

  void DelayOpening(BusyWindow window)
  {
        window.Width = 0;
        window.Height = 0;
        Task.Delay(timeToDelay).ContinueWith(_ =>
        {
            window.Dispatcher.Invoke(window.EnlargeWindow);
        });
  }
}
```

`window.EnlargeWindow` resizes the window and centers it so that it is visible to the user.

My question is related to the body of `Task.Delay.ContinuesWith`:  What happens to `window` if all of the work has been exhausted before the `ContinuesWith` body has been executed?

I've ran a few tests and everything appears to work.  No exceptions are visibly thrown in the main thread. I think I am missing something critical here.  Is there a cleaner approach?

Comment: I think your core question is "Is it safe to Invoke on a Dispatcher when the corresponding Window has been closed?". Is that right?

Comment: That sounds accurate.  And if not, what would be a better approach?

Comment: In practice, a better approach to move operations to another thread, but not creating UI in another thread.

Comment: _"Is there a cleaner approach?"_ -- given that you've tied `BatchOperationManager` to the `BusyWindow` class (seems not great to me, but it is what it is), I don't see a lot of harm in what you're doing. Depending on the caller of `Execute()`, if the window is closed before it can be enlarged, the invoked delegate may never execute, since after `ShowDialog()` has exited there won't be a message-pumping loop active. But that doesn't seem harmful. Still, without a specific problem statement, your question seems off-topic; more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com, I think.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was mostly worried that there might be an underlying problem that I could not see.  _Is there a cleaner approach?_ was assuming that there are problems when invoking a dispatcher on a closed window.  Thank you for your response!  If the answer is **No** could you answer with a reference or two?  I'd be happy to mark as accepted.

Comment: "Safe" is not exactly the right word.  But sure, WPF is going to yell at you when you call a window's Close() method more than once, it just ignores the second call.  A more sane approach is to simply not let the user close the window since that has no useful benefits at all.